# Estoy haciendo el juego del ahorcado, y necesito cambiar un string por un char? pero solo uno en una posicion

Tags: java, string, str-replace

public class remplazar {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    String sentence = "SISAS";
    String auxWord = sentence;
    int g = sentence.length()*2;
    String remplazo = "_ ";
    while(remplazo.length()< g){
        remplazo += "_ ";
    }
    auxWord = remplazo;
    System.out.println(auxWord);
    int countWin=0 ;
    int countGAmeOver=0;
        while(auxWord != sentence){
        System.out.print("Ingrese una letra:");
        String y = teclado.nextLine();
        y = y.toUpperCase();
        char chary = y.charAt(0);
        for(int x=0;x<sentence.length();x++){
        if(sentence.charAt(x)== chary ){
                    countWin++;
                    System.out.println(auxWord.replace("_ ",y ));
                    System.out.println("acertada :" + countWin);
                    break;
        }
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: Donde esta lo que no entiendes? Tenes un fallo en el código o que sucede?

Comment: Lo que he no he podido hacer es que me reemplace solo un _ me los reemplaza todos, por ejemplo si la palabra es hola e ingreso la h, al reemplazar todo me va a salir hhhh, en si esta parte es lo que tengo dificultad

Comment: Sería más sencillo si en lugar de usar cadenas de caracteres `String` utilizaras arreglos de caracteres `char[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error del cual decís está en esta parte del código:

`System.out.println(auxWord.replace("_ ",y ));`

Lo que estás haciendo es reemplazar cada "_ " por tu nuevo `char` y no el de la posición que vos realmente queres. Tenés que cambiar tu función para que solo cambie el `char` en la posición donde hubo coincidencia de caracteres.

El nuevo código quedaría así:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    String sentence = "hola";
    String auxWord = sentence;
    int g = sentence.length() * 2;
    String remplazo = "_ ";
    while (remplazo.length() < g) {
        remplazo += "_ ";
    }
    auxWord = remplazo;
    System.out.println(auxWord);
    int countWin = 0;
    int countGAmeOver = 0;
    while (countWin != sentence.length()) {
        System.out.print("Ingrese una letra:");
        String letraIntroducida = teclado.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        char chary = letraIntroducida.charAt(0);
        for (int x = 0; x < sentence.length(); x++) {
            if (sentence.toUpperCase().charAt(x) == chary) {//Modifique acá, así compara los dos char en mayuscula.
                countWin++;//cambiar la posicion de x en el string por el char.
                auxWord = cambiarString(auxWord,chary,x*2);
                System.out.println("Nuevo string: " + auxWord);
                System.out.println("acertada :" + countWin);
            }
        }
    }

}

public static String cambiarString(String sentence,char newChar,int index) {
    char[] sequence = sentence.toCharArray();
    sequence[index] = newChar;
    return new String(sequence);
}
```

***EXTRA:***

Fijate que saque el `break` del bucle for. De esa manera conseguís que se fije en todas las, por ejemplo, S de tu sentencia y no solo en la primera que encuentra.

Comment: Si, cambio, sino que ahora me imprime la palabra completa osea, por ejemplo la palabara es hola, ingreso h y se supone que debe quedar h_ _ _, pero de inmediato sale hola

Comment: Mm lo probé y funcionaba bien, ahora me fijo de nuevo

Comment: Yo lo estoy probando y funciona bien, solo cambia, por ejemplo, las S(si tu palabra tiene S) y no las demás.

Comment: bueno, y me sale este error tambien: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
 at models.remplazar.cambiarString(remplazar.java:35)
 at models.remplazar.main(remplazar.java:24)

Comment: Hablame a matiezelq@gmail.com y vemos que pasa, ami no me da ningún error :S

Comment: Ya revise, era un error que tenia, si funciona gracias

Comment: El código estaba bien al final?

Comment: si, se lo agradezco